# Playing custom audio format

Tags: android, media

Is there any possibility to play custom audio format (encoded default format) in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible--you can program your own encoder and process the audio byte by byte if you have to. That could be very very difficult, however.

Here's some information on what audio formats are supported in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

If you need a more thorough answer than that, you'll be able to get better answers from Stack Overflow with more detail. For example, what do you mean "encoded default format"? Exactly what type of audio file are you hoping to play in your program?

Comment: default means audio format that is supported by android (mp3 or aac). I've found solution like decode supported format to pcm and than play it with AudioTrack. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Are you asking how to play an MP3 file in your app? Playing an MP3 file is fine, recording an MP3 file is very difficult. For information on playing media files, check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html and here's the appropriate class api http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html